# Wiki based website - Choice of technology

Tags: grails, mediawiki, wiki, wikipedia, stackexchange

I am willing to build a wiki-based website that would have some other features, namely **comments, social sharing, video insertion, article rating and gamification**. In a nutshell, something very close to the StackExchange's websites, but the pages would consist of a single piece article instead of a thread of questions implementing the *footnote feature*.

I have not coded a single line yet.

I am rather experienced with Grails, so I know Groovy and Java. I also know JQuery and a bit of PHP, but I can learn basically everything required. I will be the only one programming on the project.

My questions are:

- Which technology should I use according to YOU ? 
  Should I use Grails as this is what I know best, and try to integrate a wiki technology within my app (if yes, which one) ?
- Should I start from an already existing wiki technology (WikiMedia, XWiki, TWiki, Moinmoin, ...) and modify it to integrate the features I need (gamification, comments, video insertion, article rating and social sharing) ? Once again, if you think that is the best solution, please quote a technology, and if possible, tell me why is this THE one.

Thank you very much for your help. I find it rather hard to choose, and ever harder to know which path is the right one to go. 
Any suggestion is most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using MediaWiki for the following reasons

1. You mentioned a wiki-based website
2. It has lots of extensions built already for your needs (comments, article rating, sharing, comments)
3. Since you mentioned you know little PHP, you can also modify some of the extensions for your use.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. 
Just to be sure I understood the GPL license correctly, I have to give public access to the source code of my application if I use the WikiMedia source code, is that right ? 
Not that this is a problem, I just want to be sure I got it right.

Comment: No, I don't think you have to worry about that

Comment: If you distribute your application, you need to distribute the source code with it. As long as you keep it to yourself, you can keep the source code to yourself. (Using it for running a webpage does not count as distribution.)

Comment: Just to be sure I understood correctly: running my website using WikiMedia code is not considered a distribution of my application. 

What would be distributing my application then? Providing tiers persons with copies of it or something of that kind?
THe GPL license is very permissive then :)

Comment: The aim of GPL is to ensure that everyone running the software has the means to modify it and share those modifications. At the same time, it tries to be permissive enough so that people actually use it. (There is actually a GPL variant called AGPL which requires you to share the code if you use it to run a web page, but it isn't very popular.)

Answer (score 1):

[MediaWiki](http://mediawiki.org/wiki/) has (via extensions) support for social sharing, video insertion and article rating, and not-great-but-okay support for comments. (Probably most other wiki platforms too - these are common enough features.) Wikia (a MediaWiki-based wiki farm who opensourced most of their custom code) has some gamification features, though I am not familiar with them. Also, MediaWiki has the advantage of having the most widely known wiki dialect (due to the popularity of Wikipedia).

That said, if you are going for minimal developement effort, I would look into adding wiki features to an existing StackOverflow clone before trying to add gamification, comment etc. features to a wiki.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. 
I will have a look at Wikia then. What do you call _"an existing StackOverflow clone"_ ? Is StackOverflow open-source ?

Comment: I actually found [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) on the topic. Very helpful! I haven't dived deeply into the codes yet but would you have any suggestion regarding an 'easy to integrate' wiki technology into any of the StackOverflow clones ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with StackOverflow clones, but given that SO itself is a wiki (even if it does a good job of hiding it), I would expect some of the more mature clones also include wiki features, and you just need to modify permissions and templates instead of adding new core functionality.